# EF Code First CTP5 Null child Object handling

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

I have a Product object with a related Category within it.

I have the relationship between product and Category as a One to Many. But the Category can also be null.

Trouble is I cannot seem to handle null Category object.

I tried the following in my Product class:

```
private Category _category;

public virtual Category Category
{
   get { return _category ?? (_category = new Category()); }

   set { _category = value; }
}
```

And on my Database Context OnModelCreating method:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasRequired(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany(c => c.Products)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId);
```

Unfortunately on accessing the Product.Category in my design layer it always returns the New Category instance, rather than try to pull the Category by the Product.CategoryId (which *does* have a value).

How can I can setup my model to handle null Category?

Comment: The model may not be the best place for this. I would recommend creating a partial class and handling it there. Is there a reason you need to handle it in your model?

Comment: But I am handling it in a class ( the Product Class ), although yes, that is the Model... Are you suggesting adding another layer between my design layer and model to check for null values?

Comment: Btw. do you know that CTP5 is outdated version? Current version is EF 4.1 RC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Category` is optional (it is because it can be null) you must use:

modelBuilder.Entity()
               .HasOptional(p => p.Category)
               .WithMany(c => c.Products)
               .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId);

And define your product as:

```
public class Product
{
    ...
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category { get; set; }
}
```